# How to configure OpenVPN to access local clients

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

**EDIT2**: Per my first edit below, I determined OpenVPN connects just fine in a public environment and routes all traffic through it. The real question is, **how do I configure my files so my desktop client routes successfully through OpenVPN?**

I want my desktop to have all the benefits of being shielded by a VPN and quite possibly allow it to be connected to remotely from a public hotspot using my laptop (though that may be a different question all together).

My router has a gateway address of 192.168.1.254, my desktop is connected to it via 192.168.1.150, and my server is connected via 192.168.1.180. My laptop can connect to the server from public Wifi, but cannot connect when connected via Wifi to the local router.

*Original Question - OpenVPN will not access HTTP servers*

I followed this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) on setting up a VPN on my web server.

The OpenVPN client connects just fine to the server (at least I think it does) and can access a couple of websites with HTTPS; however, it cannot access any regular HTTP websites and the connection tends to drop out after five or so minutes

At this point, I'm not entirely sure if my IP settings on certain files are correct because the guide wasn't too clear on what certain IP addresses should be. I'm not sure whether some IP addresses should point to the gateway router or the server's public IP.

What do I need fix in the files below to help me maintain my OpenVPN connection to my server and route all traffic through it?

Helpful facts:

- The desktop runs Windows 10 with OpenVPN GUI v11.4.0.0; the server runs Ubuntu Server 16.04. If all works well on my desktop, I'd like to be able to connect to the server remotely from my college campus using one of my laptops (with Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.2)
- The desktop and server are both connected to the same LAN on a router.
- The router's firewall is configured to forward requests on port 1194 to the server.
- Some of the lines that were commented out are left out of these files. Let me know if I should edit them back in, or add a specific log file.
- As the guide suggested, the certificates and keys are written inside the client1.ovpn file, and I've commented that data out in this post

/etc/openvpn/server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" #My server's public IP
;push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth SHA256
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

/etc/ufw/before.rules

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
#Rest of file left out for brevity
```

client1.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194 #My server's public IP
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256
key-direction 1
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
# Certificate string exists here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
# Certificate data
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
#Private key here
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
#OpenVPN static key
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

**EDIT**

Update: I created a client2 config for my laptop and took the laptop out to my school's network this morning. In that environment, OpenVPN now works fine, so the issue has something to do with my desktop and laptop being under the same LAN as my server that is causing the aforementioned connection problems.

Now that I am convinced OpenVPN does work, but something about trying to connect to it while under the same LAN causes problems, I can do some research into that specific problem and ask a new question if it comes down to it.

Comment: "The desktop and server are both connected to the same LAN on a router."  Why is the device you're trying to remote into the network, in the same network?

Comment: The server and device are both physically next to each other under my desk, hence why they're on the same network. I'm a bit new to networking and VPNs so I wrote this question assuming the desktop had to access the server through the public IP despite being on the same LAN in order for it to work. I was hoping after getting it to work on my desktop, then I could install OpenVPN on one of my laptops which could be used in public.

Comment: Just to confirm, you want the security benefits of VPN, but on the desktop still inside the same network as the VPN server, correct?

Comment: Yes. Both desktop and server are on the same network and I would like the security offered by the OpenVPN software from the server by routing the desktop's internet traffic through the server (at least that's how I think it works or should work, correct me if I'm wrong in that assumption). I'm not sure how the configuration files should be set to accomplish this; whether it be remoting in through the server's public IP, remote through private IP, or something different I'm missing.

Comment: The point of a VPN, is to encrypt your connection to the network your computer is connecting to.  This is redundant, as your computer is already in the network the VPN server is running in.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand yet why this setup would be redundant. To be more clear, I want the desktop's connection to go through the VPN to be shielded/encrypted, then go to the gateway router, then to the Web. Or is there something else I'm missing? Thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: The point of the encryption is so that all of your communications with the network you're joining is secure.  So if you access a file on that network, anybody who may have intercepted the packets wouldn't be able to read it (without decrypting it).  Having that encryption inside your network would only make sense if you think other people inside the network are trying to steal your data.

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to test the VPN, would be to configure a device not inside the same network as the VPN server.

While there are situations where internal network VPNs are useful (such as ensuring privacy and resource compartmentalization), they are only feasible in a corporate environment.  Even more, there are other methods to prevent individuals from accessing resources that their role does not require, such as Virtual LANs (VLAN).

As far as your configuration files go, I don't see any errors in them.  I compared them to configuration files I used for my VPN, and don't see any inconsistency.  Try to configure one of your laptops the way your desktop is set up.  I'm betting that it will work, but if it doesn't, update your question.  If it is the latter, I would wager that the VPN service in your server may be having issues.

Comment: I took my laptop out for a test drive under my home LAN and school's WiFi. It still had trouble in the same environment as the desktop, but the OpenVPN service seems to work perfectly under the campus connection. So you are right, the program works outside the local network, but something about making a connection within that network is causing trouble. I'll update my question to reflect these new findings.